# tesseract unable to read image tile

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

i am writing a program to extract information from Govt. ID's and use contours to extract characters from the image (since passing it as is, into tesseract results in junk output). I have tried this approach with other printed documents and it yields much better results than passing the whole image into tesseract. But for some reason, with the govt id images, it seems to either give "Error in pixGenHalftoneMask: pix too small" (though the images are at least 100x100) or blank output. I am attaching both images used

[image: image of "M" ..for some strange reason its tilted here]
[image: this one too is tilted , though on windows it appears normally]

I used psm 10 for the image with an "M" and 8 for the other image and yet it bore no fruit. I have a feeling the character is just too thick ? i tried erosion as well ..but the end result was the same :( .. any pointers please ?

Comment: Can you please try to binarize your image before feeding it to tesseract.

Comment: Hi Dmitri ..thanks for the tip but i am trying the binarized images itself ..i must apologize for not putting them above. Could you think of any other reason ? just fyi, the background of this ID is pale blue while for literally all white b/g cards , even with similar images, OCR works great (theoretically binarization should be able to take care of it but im clueless )

Comment: You can also put some white border (~10pix) around your binarized image, sometimes tesseract gets confused when it tries to calculate a font size